# Assigning values to typescript objects

Tags: typescript, interface

I'm trying to create a power BI custom visual.
I have a typescript interface `BiHiSankey` in my interfaces file.

```
   declare module 'd3' {

    interface BiHiSankey {
          nodeSpacing: () => number;
          nodeWidth: () => number;
          collapsedNodes: () => d3.Selection<any>
                          }
    export var biHiSankey: () => BiHiSankey
                    }
```

And in my visual.ts file ,I have done this,

```
let BiHi=d3.biHiSankey();
BiHi.nodeWidth(20);
```

But assigning a value to the `nodeWidth` using this method result in an error,`Expected 0 arguments,but got 1`.

I don't understand why this happens.I'm kind of new to typescript,Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare separate overloads for getting and setting the value.

```
interface BiHiSankey {
    nodeSpacing(): number;
    nodeSpacing(value: number): void;
    nodeWidth(): number;
    nodeWidth(value: number): void;
}
let BiHi=d3.biHiSankey();
BiHi.nodeWidth(20); // set value
BiHi.nodeWidth(); // get value
```

**Note**: This is assuming the functions declared in `JS` support this functionality.

Comment: what does `() => ` mean ?

Comment: That is the syntax for declaring a function type. This is usually used when you want to set the function from outside the object. The way you can overload function types is limited. Using the method syntax is better in this case to allow different overloads.